# (Asterisk PBX) How to control program written in C from asterisk agi in features.conf

Tags: c, dynamic, asterisk, pipeline, agi

How to control programs written in C from asterisk AGI-application in features.conf?
I want to control my program by pushing keys on the telephone (dtmf-tones). I was reading about using pipes for passing on standard I/O. My first idea was:

```
$ Asterisk | c_program
```

then have standard output in AGI-script by `printf()`

The second idea was to use:

```
$ printf parameter_a >> file
```

to write to file and then let my c-program read the file and evaluate the contents as parameter.

Has anyone tried out or has experience with similar tasks/problems?

Answer (score 0):

there are no way do like u show.

posible solutions:

1) Run your program with arguments using system(). you can do that with or without AGI.

2) Use linux pipe(special files)

3) Start your program as AGI/EAGI script, your program must work acordinly, see [CAGI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cagi/)

4) Use database table(task) and asterisk realtime for put record in it.

most correct is 3) if ur program is not demon and 2,4 if ur program is demon.

also you can use in dialplan